# How this type of image displays are done with scikit-learn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I was watching a tutorial on machine learning. The tutorial has a csv file and some python codes. And it was saying that if I implement this code then I will get the visual of data. But, when I tried those codes with Jupyter notebook there is no visual like them at all. I shared you the data file and codes bellow if you guys can help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

**Here is the visual of the data they have generated** 
[image]

**Here is the data.csv file**
[csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15xYCZ4nYJRHXNrFFA5vhdnqlHfrLTJwR/view?usp=sharing)

**Here is the code**

```
import pandas
import numpy
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')

X = numpy.array(data[['x1', 'x2']])
y = numpy.array(data['y'])

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X,y)

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(X,y)

classifier = SVC()
classifier.fit(X,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. run the fitting process and get the model parameters as a result
2. define a 2-dimensional area where your trainings data are somehow in the center
3. compute a (x,y) mesh for that area
4. run the model for each (x,y)-point of the mesh
5. plot the result with matplotlib pcolormesh

[Here](https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/basic-steps-machine-learning.html) a coded example. The dividing lines are an additional task.You could draw isolines (1 isoline with matplotlib contour) for that.

Comment: Thank you very much Pyano for your prompt help. The instructions you have given are very hard for me. Could you please write me those code for an easy understanding?

Comment: To keep the post clear some functions are at the end of the post. Otherwise it's a step by step explanation code I have written: https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/basic-steps-machine-learning.html

Comment: Thank you again. I am trying to learn what you have said in your post.

Comment: Fine. Please give me a feedback occasionally wether the post was more  helpfull or more confusing

Comment: The post is helpful undoubtedly but for a novice like me is nearly out of reach. I found that you created a python function called **generate_data_1D()** which I can't understand to use with my code. Besides, I noticed that you have also written some functions for visualizing the data. I think they both are for advance level readers. Yet I will keep studying your post. Thanks a lot for your kind support.