# sklearn finding the name of linear regression coefficient

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**Question: How can I find out which feature does the output coefficients belongs to without manually tracking the order of feature fed into linear regresion**

I have a datasets with following feature.
`usertype` contains `Subscriber` & `Customer`.

[image]

I  `train_test_split` the data.

```
feature = ['age','usertype','gender']

X = citibike_dropped[feature]
y = citibike_dropped['tripduration']


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=123)
```

I used sklearn `Pipeline` to pre-processes and fit into linear regression

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [('ohe',OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'),['usertype']),
    ('scaler',MinMaxScaler(),['age'])],
    remainder = 'passthrough')

lr = LinearRegression()


Input = [('transformer',ct),('clf',lr)]
pipe = Pipeline(Input)
```

I check the coefficient after fitting the `pipe` with `x_train and y_train`

```
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train);
pipe.named_steps['clf'].coef_
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array([  0.        , 499.85347478, 177.64720307])
```

How can I find out which feature does the above coefficients belongs to?**

Comment: what i mean is the `w`. for example `y = 0*usertype+ 499 *gender + 177*64*age + c`?

Comment: @PrakashDahal is scikit-learn, `coef_` is `w` and `intercept_` is `b`

Comment: features might be in the order that you have fed to the model like `feature = ['age','usertype','gender']`. `y = 0*age+ 499 *usertype+ 177.64*gender+ c`

Comment: @PrakashDahal I believe the `coef_` will be  how the `ColumnTransformer` feed into the `linear regression`. In this case it will be `OneHotEncoder`:`usertype` , followed by `StandardScaler`:`age`, then `passthrough`:`Gender`. But this way, i have to keep track manually. If given a large feature and multiple pipeline, manual keep track might be difficult. so I was wondering is there any function that can return the coef_ name

Answer (score 0):

Pherhaps you might have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426413/how-this-type-of-image-displays-are-done-with-scikit-learn/58426682#58426682) or [here](https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/basic-steps-machine-learning.html) to find the decision line or the area that belongs to the feature